# How to test PushNotification in IOS simulator Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios-simulator

How to Test push notification in IOS simulators using Xcode 11.4 and above without using an ios device.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Xcode 11.4 and above support testing of push notifications using simulators.

To test,

### Option 1 - Using the "ControlRoom" Mac app created by Paul Hudson (author of https://www.hackingwithswift.com/)

Controlroom is an amazing app which i came across recently which allows to control the simulators. It provides a nice UI to customise the notifications.
Special thanks to Paul Hudson for sharing the source code in git.
Git URL - https://github.com/twostraws/ControlRoom

[image]

### Option 2 - Using Terminal

run the following command in the terminal

```
xcrun simctl push <simulator identifier> <bundle identifier of the app> <pushcontentfile>.apns"
```

#### How to get Simulator identifier using Xcode

```
Xcode Menu => Window => Devices and Simulators
```

[image]

#### Format of .apns file

- Save the push notification payload (json format) to a file with an extension ".apns"

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Push Notifications Test",
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 1
    }
}
```

### Option 3 - Drag and Drop .apns file to the simulator

The .apns file should contain the bundle identifier of the app as a part of the payload

```
{
    "Simulator Target Bundle": "<bundle identifier of the app>",
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Push Notifications Test",
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer and options 

Comment: To get the simulator ID do: `xcrun simctl list | egrep '(Booted)'`

Comment: Also try: http://pushplayground.com/ It's a free web tool to test push notifications

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed that I can push notifications via. **APNs** to **iOS 16** simulators running on my mac. It worked without needing to create "files" and emulate push notifications. Perhaps you need Xcode 14.0, that's what I used.

Just push the notification to the device as normal (e.g. using firebase_messaging, or my script: https://github.com/ben-xD/push/blob/main/tools/ios/send_ios_example)

[image]